# Extensions of the algebraic numbers

Tags: pi

I have two extensions of the algebraic numbers, and I'd like to know whether they are equivalent.

**Definition 1.** $x \in \mathbb E_1$ iff $x$ is a root of $e^{P(x)} + Q(x)$ with $P, Q$ some polynomials with integer coefficients.

**Definition 2.** $x \in \mathbb E_2$ iff $x$ is a root of $e^{P(x)} + Q(x)$ with $P, Q$ some polynomials with integer complex coefficients. (Here, integer complex coefficients are  numbers in the form $a+bi$, with $a,b \in \mathbb Z$.)

It is easy to see they are both countable, so we can't get a contradiction form there.

I don't think they are equivalent, because with definition 2  we can make $\pi$ since it is a root of $e^{ix} +1$.

> **Question:** Are $\mathbb E_1$ and $\mathbb E_2$ the same set?

Comment: That's a weird choice of tags.

Comment: Take $P(x) = 0$ and you get algebraic numbers.

Comment: I have clarified the question.

Comment: Are looking at those sets, or the fields they generate within the complex numbers?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The sets. So I'd like to have either a proof that every number in $\mathbb E_1$ is a member of $\mathbb E_2$ and vice versa, or a number that is in only one of the sets.

Comment: It's possibly an open question as to whether $e^{\pi^2}$ is _rational_ or not. (I know similar quantities, such as $\pi^e$ and $e+\pi$ are not known.) So $\pi$ might be an element of both. ($e^\pi$ _is_ known to be transcendental, though.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Why isn't this set theory?

Comment: Because not every question involving sets is set theory.

Comment: $\pi\in\Bbb{E}_2$ for sure. What about $\Bbb{E}_1$?